# Can't remove nodejs

Tags: apt, nodejs

I would like to remove node v7 and leave only v8, but can't figure it out how to do that. Here is what I'm doing:

```
rd@rd-asus:~$ sudo apt-get purge node
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'node' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 360 not upgraded.

rd@rd-asus:~$ node --version
v7.10.0

rd@rd-asus:~$ nodejs --version
v8.3.0
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg -S $(which node)`?

Answer (score 0):

First find which version of node is installed on your system :

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i node
```

After that you can use both `dpkg` and `apt` to remove it . First I suggest use :

```
$ dpkg -r node-version-you-find
```

then If you get any dependencies error try using :

```
$ apt remove node-version-you-find
```